# Springboot Redis not save in cache if return value is false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I need to save this cache once `response` is `true` only.

If it is `false` then no need to save it in the cache.

```java
@Cacheable(value = RedisCacheConfig.CONFIGURATION_CACHE, key  = "#username.concat('_').concat(#channel)", cacheManager = RedisCacheConfig.CACHE_MANAGER)
public Boolean getConfigurations( String username, String channel, ValidateAccess validateAccess){
    Boolean response = configurationService.validateAdAndFetchRole(username, validateAccess);
    return response;
}
```

How I can achieve this logic here?

Comment: So for `false` you'd like to query again and again?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, If it returned `false` then query again.

Comment: In that case try something like `unless="#result == false"` of `unless="#{!result}"`. However, note that `Boolean` also would allow for `null` values so if those are possible and you only want to cache `true` then maybe it should be `unless="#{result != true}"`

Comment: Thanks @Thomas  `unless="#result == false"` working well. Thanks once again.